# Firefox JPM not showing any thing

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I want to develop a Firefox addon, however I'm not able to complete the Addon SDK installation. I followed https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Installation this link, but when I type jpm in the terminal it shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and install node.js (from here: https://nodejs.org/en/).
Once installed, open a command prompt and install jpm, by typing
"npm install jpm --global".
Close the cmd prompt, open another and jpm should be available

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you didn't install latest version of nodejs so follow this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server